# IDE supporting WAS

Tags: eclipse

Hello all,

Can anyone tell me which IDE I can use to do development towards WAS 7.0?
Please help me out with the answer very soon. I have checked Netbeans 6.5 beta and it does not have the support for it. Also on the [MyEclipse Blue Edition](http://myeclipseide.com/blue.php) page it says Compatible with WebSphere 5.x, 6.0, 6.1, 7, but in http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=98487 I see "WebSphere Application Server V7.0 is not supported by MyEclipse at the moment. Thats the reasons you guys are running into issues."

Anyone please help me out with this issue ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Rational Application Developer 7.5

Answer (score 0):

If you want proper support for WAS, you should be using the Rational toolset. RAD/RSA and their brethren are optimized for Websphere (as you'd expect given they're both from IBM).

You can do it with baseline Eclipse (I'd use the "real" Eclipse rather than myeclipse) but the easiest set up will be with Rational. You may not want to spend the money however.

It's well worth the cost, since it comes bundled with WAS test environments and can deploy automatically to other WAS instances (for example, system test environments).

RAD 7.5 supports WAS 7 so I'd go for that one. RAD 7 only supports up to WAS 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

See [Compare Eclipse Packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) for a nice chart